# JDeveloper deleting ADF resource bundle reference from VO source

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using JDeveloper version 11.1.1.7.0 for an ADF project. Whenever I edit a View Object that uses a resource bundle to provide labels via UI hints for things like input text fields and table column headers, the resource bundle reference at the end of the VO XML source gets automatically removed by JDeveloper. This means that every time I want to add a new attribute, change a binding, etc I must go to the History tab and restore the resource bundle reference before running my application. Otherwise, the labels are just displayed as the raw attribute names from the VO (e.g. "employeeName" instead of "Employee Name" from the resource bundle).

This is not just an issue for me, but for everyone on my team. At best, it's a constant annoyance. At worst, bugs get filed because labels are missing and inexperienced developers think they need to redefine every single label, which is a huge waste of time. I've searched on Oracle Support and can't find any patch for this. Google doesn't find anything useful. Does anyone else have this issue? Know what might be causing it and of a way to fix it?

ETA: Even if you've encountered this but don't have a solution, please post a comment stating this. Part of my question is whether this is an issue unique to the project I'm working on, or whether it's a common JDeveloper bug.

ETA: For the record, this is still a problem with version 12.1.3.

Comment: I had no problem with disappearing resource bundles, however I've often notice that 11.1.1.7 jdeveloper removes some properties, like parameters in taskflow or something like that. Only solution to avoid bugs caused by this issue is to use some version control solution and check every commit you do.

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to us and this had caused regression issue in the past for us. We have had to redo the labels everytime we edit the view object. I guess this is a jdeveloper bug.